How to do a generic reusable rules in Boost::Spirit::x3?
In a parser I am currently working on, I am writing some rules/"sub-parser" whose size is rather significant. The thing is: as this parser can demand a certain effort from the compiler and can have a certain size, I would like to translate and instantiate it only once and thereby write the rule like explained in the boost tutorial. So far, so good. BUT, this rule will be meant to be reused frequently by different parsers whose attribute type is always different.
I will illustrate my problem with the trivial example below which is already something a tried and that won't build. my_rule is the rule that has to be reusable. I want it to be usable in three parsing rules for Foo, Bar and Baz. They each represent possible use cases of re-usability I could encounter. So far, as shown in the example, I tried to use a boost::fusion::vector a generic attribute for all of the use cases but it ain't that easy. The parsing rules for Foo and Baz build but the one for Bar does not.
Thus, my question is, in the light of this example: How to make my_rule work in every use case ? What to use as an attribute ? Would it be at least possible ? I would be ready to hear "no".
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/binary.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

struct Foo
{
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct Bar
{
  int c;
  int d;
  int e;
};

struct Baz
{
  int f;
  Foo foo;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Foo, a, b);
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Bar, c, d, e);
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Baz, f, foo);

const auto my_rule =
  x3::rule<class My_rule_tag, boost::fusion::vector<int, int>>{ "my-rule" } %=
  x3::byte_ >> x3::byte_;

const auto foo_rule = x3::rule<class Foo_rule_tag, Foo>{ "foo-rule" } %=
  my_rule;

const auto bar_rule = x3::rule<class Bar_rule_tag, Bar>{ "bar-rule" } %=
  x3::byte_ >> my_rule;

const auto baz_rule = x3::rule<class Bar_rule_tag, Baz>{ "baz-rule" } %=
  x3::byte_ >> my_rule;

int
main()
{
  std::vector<std::uint8_t> frame{ 0x03, 0x06, 0x09 };
  // Build OK
  Foo foo1;
  x3::parse(frame.begin(), frame.end(), foo_rule, foo1);
  // Build NOK
  Bar bar1;
  x3::parse(frame.begin(), frame.end(), bar_rule, bar1);
  // Build OK
  Baz baz1;
  x3::parse(frame.begin(), frame.end(), baz_rule, baz1);
  return 0;
}


To be honest the goal seems conflicted. For generic and reusable you want the rules to be in the same TU as the invocation.
As you've already figured out (see Baz aggregating Foo) the key is to make the attribute types compatible for attribute propagation.
The simplest thing I can think of:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/binary.hpp>

template <typename T> constexpr static T parse(auto const& frame, auto rule) {
    T val;
    parse(begin(frame), end(frame), rule, val);
    return val;
}

struct Foo { int a, b;       constexpr auto operator<=>(Foo const&) const = default; };
struct Bar { int c, d, e;    constexpr auto operator<=>(Bar const&) const = default; };
struct Baz { int f; Foo foo; constexpr auto operator<=>(Baz const&) const = default; };
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Foo, a, b)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Bar, c, d, e)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Baz, f, foo.a, foo.b)

// using Vec2 = boost::fusion::vector<int, int>;
namespace x3  = boost::spirit::x3;

auto const vec2_    = x3::byte_ >> x3::byte_;
auto const foo_rule = vec2_;
auto const bar_rule = x3::byte_ >> vec2_;
auto const baz_rule = x3::byte_ >> foo_rule;

int main() {
    constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, 3> frame{0x03, 0x06, 0x09};
    assert((parse<Foo>(frame, foo_rule) == Foo{ 3, 6 }));
    assert((parse<Bar>(frame, bar_rule) == Bar{ 3, 6, 9 }));
    assert((parse<Baz>(frame, baz_rule) == Baz{ 3, {6, 9} }));
}


note the adaptation of Baz!

If you want {foo,bar,baz}_rule properly compilation-firewalled:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/binary.hpp>

template <typename T> constexpr static T parse(auto const& frame, auto rule) {
    T val;
    parse(begin(frame), end(frame), rule, val);
    return val;
}

struct Foo { int a, b;       constexpr auto operator<=>(Foo const&) const = default; };
struct Bar { int c, d, e;    constexpr auto operator<=>(Bar const&) const = default; };
struct Baz { int f; Foo foo; constexpr auto operator<=>(Baz const&) const = default; };
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Foo, a, b)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Bar, c, d, e)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Baz, f, foo)

// using Vec2 = boost::fusion::vector<int, int>;
namespace x3  = boost::spirit::x3;

auto const vec2_    = x3::byte_ >> x3::byte_;
auto const foo_rule = x3::rule<class Foo_rule_tag, Foo>{"foo_rule"} = vec2_;
auto const bar_rule = x3::rule<class Bar_rule_tag, Bar>{"bar_rule"} = x3::byte_ >> vec2_;
auto const baz_rule = x3::rule<class Baz_rule_tag, Baz>{"baz_rule"} = x3::byte_ >> foo_rule;

int main() {
    constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, 3> frame{0x03, 0x06, 0x09};
    assert((parse<Foo>(frame, foo_rule) == Foo{ 3, 6 }));
    assert((parse<Bar>(frame, bar_rule) == Bar{ 3, 6, 9 }));
    assert((parse<Baz>(frame, baz_rule) == Baz{ 3, {6, 9} }));
}

If vec2_ (probably a packet header of sorts) is "involved" then

either aggregate it just like you did in Baz
include it's generic definition in each TU that needs it

To be completely honest, seperating your parser across TUs is never worth
it, especially for X3. The compile times are already very low, and the
explicit instantiations hard-lock the iterator as well as the context types,
often leading to inscrutable linker errors.
See e.g.

Mixing non-terminal rules from separeted translation unit
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE not understand

OUT OF THE BOX
Since it looks like you're actually binary-serializing packed structs (with
some application specific wire representation), consider generating your parsers and
serializers e.g. using Boost Describe.

Thank you for the answer!
I never heard of boost describe and it looks pretty interesting.
I am gonna avoid seperating the parsers TUs.
However, if wanted to use the same rule/sequence in many TUs/files what would be the best to do ? Defining an auto inline method() that would return the sequence/rule ?

I would expose a higher-level function that drives the parser like MyT parseT(std::span<uint8_t const>);. That way you can successfully decouple your application from any implementation details

But I mean, if foo_rule and bar_rule were in two different TUs and vec2_ was an huge rule/sequence, how would you achieve to make it accessible to both foo_rule and bar_rule

@PlayerK you would really have to do the documentation thing you linked to. Again, I think that if that's required (a) something else is wrong (b) X3 or any other EDSL parser generator may not be a good fit.

@PlayerK why not define vec2_rule with the desired attribute of the, as you say, huge rule/sequence, and then replace vec2_ everywhere with vec2_rule.  Then, in vec2_rule.cpp define the rhs of vec2_rule as vec2_rule_def just as shown here.  Only substitute vec2_rule for grammar.

@Player, code solves the "huge rule/sequence" problem by allowing compilation in a separate *my_rule.cpp file.  It also can solve the Bar test if macro USE_GEN_TRANSFORM_PARSER is defined and compiler uses the -I flag to here.

@LarryEvans does this do anything that the OP-linked docs don't?

@sehe, it does almost the same, but makes it explicit and solves the "mismatched attribute size" problem when the 2nd test(the bar_rule test) is compiled.  And Seth, your Apr 22 comment suggested PayerK's approach maybe be wrong and the example solution I provided gives you a target to explain why it maybe wrong.

@PlayerK, maybe you could provide a more realistic example of the "huge rule/sequence" problem to illustrate maybe reduced compile times and greater convenience by not needed to repeat the my_rule_def in multiple TU's.

@LarryEvans for all the usual reasons why things can be wrong in c++: if you write code that takes an enormity to compile, you can usually make things more lightweight. In particular for Spirit code, I'm thinking of "swimming against the current", e.g. forcing many non-default behaviors (coercing, semantic actions, switching skippers etc.). In my experience there has never been a need to separate rules in different TUs. If the grammar is actually too large, I'd be using ANTLR or something like that.
